# findContours gives distinct results for "same" images

Tags: opencv

I've tried findContours with 2 images. Actually, they are one. One is color image (jpg), the other is created from the color one by MS paint (exported to monochrome image - bmp):

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

char* org_file =  "expmap_1.bmp"; //"expmap.jpg"; // "pic1.png";  

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
Mat src;
// the first command line parameter must be file name of binary
// (black-n-white) image

src = imread(org_file, 0);  // both are read in binary form


Mat dst = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);


//  src = src > 1;
namedWindow( "Source", 1 );
imshow( "Source", src );

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours( src, contours, hierarchy,
CV_RETR_LIST  , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

// iterate through all the top-level contours,
// draw each connected component with its own random color

cout << contours.size() << endl;

int idx = 0;
for( ; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0] )
{
//  Scalar color( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
//Scalar color(255,255,255);
drawContours( dst, contours, idx, RGB(0,0,255), 1, 8, hierarchy );
}

namedWindow( "Components", 1 );
imshow( "Components", dst );
waitKey(0);
```

}

the command works with monochrome image giving correct result, but the other returns only 1 contour which is the image frame.

is there any difference between 2 cases?

Pictures that I used: 
** Color one:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/440/picture73q.jpg/

** Bitmap one:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/picture73l.png/

You can see that they are the same, just different in type (color/monochrome) which I've also converted in OpenCV code.

I've come around and is still stuck at this

PS: Anyone helps me to show the upload images right in the post? so that helpers do not have to click to see

Comment: I dont know how to upload images here. Basically, two images are the same, an indoor image with some obstacles. One is colored jpg, the other is monochrome created from the colored

Comment: you can upload image at imageshack.us and provide the link here. It is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contour#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29), it clearly says "Finds contours in a binary image", this is due to the way the implemented algorithm works. And notice the input image should be "an 8-bit single-channel image".

**Edit**: imread(,flags=0) returns a grayscale image and the pixels are not binarized. One way to do that is to use the [threshold](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) function. Then the result image can be used for findContours(). Let me know how it goes.

**Edit 2**: see [imread](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) in the documentation. It's clearly stated flags "=0 Return a grayscale image", that's not a binarized image! Hence there is no mistake here in the documentation.

**Edit 3**: findContours indeed does thresholding, but the threshold is at 0. And if you want a higher threshold you must first binarize the image at a higher threshold and pass the result image to findContours. What you have done MS paint is binarizing the image at a higher threshold. I know this can be really confusing if you don't know the details of the algorithms. The OpenCV documentation doesn't do deep and explain everything, understanding how all these algorithms work requires a hefty book. I'm not defending the OpenCV documentation, which I have nothing to do with, but I still see no mistake in the explanation. Though, novice users could perhaps benefit from a more in depth discussion of how the algorithm works.

Comment: is my code correct at this: "src = imread(org_file, 0);  // both are read in binary form"?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. This is like a bug of OpenCV API doccument => "image – The source, an 8-bit single-channel image. Non-zero pixels are treated as 1’s, zero pixels remain 0’s - the image is treated as binary " and the book OpenCV of Gary Bradski says the same thing. Gray image should be OK!! However, like what you said, I did the thresholding and it works. Strange! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I just edited the answer again, if that answered your question it's supposed to be selected as the answer by you!

Comment: sigh .. you didn't even read my comment. According to reference, findContours accepts even gray scale image. But in real, there is some slight difference. that's why I called it a BUG!

Comment: :-) I see where the confusion is, I just updated the answer. It's important you understand the reason behind this behavior of the function. If it's still unclear I'll be happy to help and explain it.